# How do Flow Control and Congestion control work together?

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpip

I am trying to learn about Flow Control and Congestion Control in TCP.

So far I understand that flow control uses the sliding window method and the receiver advertises a receive window based on how much space it has in the receive buffer.
I also understand that congestion control mechanism is in place to make sure that the network is not overwhelmed and as soon as the sender detects some packet loss, it cuts back the congestion window and slows down the sending rate.

My question might be really dumb here, but will a situation arise where the receive buffer advertises a large receive window but the network might not be able to accomodate such large segments of data hence causing network congestion? In other words, in any situation do cwnd and rwnd advertise conflicting values?

Comment: That would depend on [the implementation, of which there are at least 23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control#Algorithms)